# cURL response is asking for a web.config file to write the error to

Tags: jquery, curl

Note: the request is being sent from php to a asp.net server, you can see the URL below. As far as I know this should work, but i get a confounding html error message instead of a nice json data response!
Here are the inputs:
Querystring:  _tsmp = "1389427807768"
Request Payload: 
        {"start":0,"length":20,"sortBy":"dc","sortAscending":false,"providerId":128391,"currencyIds":[],"fromDateStr":"2007-01-01","toDateStr":"2014-01-11","validTrades":true,"lotSize":2}

**File localhost/test/proxy.php ** processes the request from jquery ajax

```
<?php
$input = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$jdv = json_decode($input, true);


date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');
$url = 'http://www.zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx/GetProviderTrades?_tsmp'.$_GET['_tsmp']; 

foreach($_GET as $getname => $getvar) {
    $fields[$getname] = urlencode($getvar); //for proxying get request to POST.
}

foreach($jdv as $postname => $postvar) {
if(is_array($postvar))$postvar = implode(",",$postvar);
    $fields[$postname ] = urlencode($postvar); //for proxying POST requests.
}

$fields_string = "";
//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

**Response**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Runtime Error</title>
    <style>
     body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
     p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
     H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
     pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
     .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
     .version {color: gray;}
     .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
     .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">

        <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

        <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>

        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

        <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
        <br><br>

        <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <code><pre>

&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

&lt;configuration&gt;
&lt;system.web&gt;
    &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;
&lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>

        <br>

        <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the &quot;defaultRedirect&quot; attribute of the application&#39;s &lt;customErrors&gt; configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.<br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <code><pre>

&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

&lt;configuration&gt;
&lt;system.web&gt;
    &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;RemoteOnly&quot; defaultRedirect=&quot;mycustompage.htm&quot;/&gt;
&lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>

        <br>

</body>
```

What do I do? I made the files put them in the root as directed, ensured the write file is writable, and i get nothing.

Comment: Which application are you putting it in the root of?

Comment: The proxy.php file is in a folder on my localhost, so I put the web.config file in the localhost root (var/www).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're seeing is saying "something" went wrong - and is suggesting that you enable remote errors on the ASP.Net host by editing its web.config to tell you more. It might be because the server has a fault, or it could be fault in the request you're making, so either attach a debugger to your ASP.Net site, or enable remote errors

Comment: Okay, so it's hiding the error. I don't have access to that server, so I can't do anything about the web.config .  So does anything jump out at you that could be wrong with the request?  You can check out what the original request looks like on this page: http://www.zulutrade.com/trader/128391

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not using the [SOAP interface](http://www.zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx?op=GetProviderTrades) (as described in their [WSDL](http://www.zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx?op=GetProviderTrades))

Comment: I was wondering why they use "webservices" in the url )) Thanks! How did you know there was a soap interface?

Comment: it's an .asmx file - they tend to behave the same (of course, things can be done to hide that, or something else could be masquerading under that URL)